# How widespread is the subjective theory of value ?

Tags: value

I typically see the subjective theory of value supported by pro-free market type individuals. But in the present day what theory of value is used for other schools of thought that favor things such as mixed market economies, Keynesianism, socialism, etc ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "subjective theory of value ?"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjective_theory_of_value    and

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/subjective-theory-of-value.asp

Comment: If you think this has anything to do with "pro-free market type individuals", read [A General Theory of Exploitation and Class](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674435865&content=reviews) by John Roemer.